# What determines the order of enqueued styles?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

Typically when I add stylesheets I use `wp_enqueue_style` multiple times within a single function, then call that function once with `wp_enqueue_scripts`. There doesn't seem to be any logic to the order those sheets loaded. They don't load in the order they are listed, or any other reasonable order I can find.

I understand how to use priority on actions, but that requires a unique function for use with each hook. I'm currently using that to overcome this issue, but I'm curious. Is there something that determines how styles are loaded when several are enqueued within the same function? And if not why?

Answer (score 2):

In the [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) for `wp_enqueue_style`, there is an argument for dependencies.

So if I enqueue style A with deps B and C, A will be loaded after B and C. :)

Comment: I'm aware of that. I'm trying to figure out what sets the order when there are no listed dependencies.

Comment: It's like priorities I guess. If two enqueues have the same deps, then it's like having the same priority. It doesn't matter which one loads first